# How to add table component in pageheadersection

Tags: telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

**Requirement**: I have a requirement to display data in table format in page header section

**Note** : I am using Telerik Reporting Q2 2015 version.

When I try to adding table component in pageheader section it displaying below error:

[image]

Is there any other options to show data in table format in header section?

Answer (score 1):

you need to  form a table structure in the header Section  . first add a panel  or a rectangle in  the header section  and then  use textbox's to  form  rows and columns   this may server the purpose .

Comment: yes good suggestion i tried with text-boxes to get form table structure, but it causing design issues if on of the  text value is multi line(more than one line). any other idea?.

Comment: First check  the maximum  multi-line data which  will  going to  fit in  text box and increase the width of page-header accordingly. 
Second option  you  can do is add panel outside your structure this will  keep  all  the text-box together.